# Characterization of orthogonal projections in terms of operator norms

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I want to show the following equivalence: If $X$ is a Hilbert Space and $P\in B(X)$ (i.e. $P$ is bounded and linear) and $P^2=P$, then

$$
(\text{im}\,P)^{\perp} =\ker P\iff ||P||\le 1
$$

I know that $||P||\le 1$ is necessary condition: $||Px||^2=\langle Px,Px\rangle = \langle Px, x\rangle \le ||Px|| \cdot ||x||$, but how does one deduce converse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $x$ we have $x=Px+(x-Px)$ where $Px\in \operatorname{im}P$ and $(x-Px)\in \ker P$. So, $\ker P$ is a complement of $\operatorname{im} P$. Suppose it is *not* an orthogonal complement; then there exist  $u\in \operatorname{im}P$ and $v\in \ker P$ such that $\operatorname{Re}\langle u, v \rangle < 0$.

For sufficiently small $t>0$ we have $\|u+tv\| < \|u\|$. Since $P(u+tv)=u$, it follows that $\|P\|>1$.